# Wordpress POD CMS Plugin error

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$tbl_row_id in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/pods/classes/PodAPI.php on line 1073
```

I keep getting this error after clicking to add a new record for a POD I created. Nothing makes sense. I deleted the whole database and tried again but keep getting the same error.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like something you'd have more luck with here: http://podscms.org/qna/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

yes i did post there and turns out that it was a bug. I just had to re-install. It'll be fixed in the next release.